# Standard Deviation of product of two Gaussian Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, monte-carlo

If we have, $Z = XY,$ where $X$ and $Y$ have Gaussian Distribtuion, and both are independent.

*I solved with the Monte Carlo Algorithm, it shows some values of Standard Deviation, but I don't know what is the formula for finding the Standard deviation of* **product of two Gaussian Distribution** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $X = N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1), Y = N(\mu_2, \sigma^2_2)$ independent .
$E[Z] = E[X]E[Y] = \mu_1\mu_2$.
$E[Z^2] = E[X^2]E[Y^2] = (\sigma_1^2+\mu_1^2)(\sigma_2^2+\mu_2^2)$

$Var(Z) = (\sigma_1^2+\mu_1^2)(\sigma_2^2+\mu_2^2) - \mu_1^2\mu_2^2$

Comment: Thanks a lot....

Comment: square root to get standard deviation

Comment: Thanks a lot, if you donot mind, could you please again write the formula of Standard Deviation of quotient Gaussian Distribution. $Z$ = $X$ / $Y$, both are independent.

Comment: $Z = X / Y$, so $X = ZY$. Use formula above to find $Var(X)$ in terms of $Z$, $Y$.
I.e. $\sigma_x^2= (\sigma_z^2 + \mu_z^2)(\sigma_y^2 + \mu_y^2)-\mu_z^2 \mu_y^2$
$\mu_x = \mu_z \mu_y$
Now knowing that $\mu_z = \mu_x / \mu_y$, we can solve the above equation for $\sigma_z^2$.

Comment: We are writing a report in our University, If you don't mind, could you please share the source of this formula? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haha I am the source. So essentially what we are doing here is applying the same logic as before where $Z=XY$, but with $X=ZY$, and $Z$ having unknown mean and variance (though we know it is Gaussian).

Comment: I mean Standard Deviation of "multiplication of Gaussain Distribution" formula reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $:$ Independence $\implies$ Uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the guy published a paper on this topic.

[link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332333452_Mean_and_Variance_of_the_Product_of_Random_Variables)